# JS, correct syntax from arrow to normal

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im learning and trying to understand javascript, and in a video im following, the dude used this code

```
app.post('/content/uploads', (req,res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send('testing');
  })
});
```

now im trying to convert it to normal, i understand that `app.post('/content/uploads', (req,res) => {`
 translates to `app.post('/content/uploads', function(req, res){`

but when i try to do `upload(req, res, (err) => {`, i cant.

What i tried is

```
upload(function(req, res, (err)){
```

but i get an error in

```
upload(function(req, res, (err)){
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
```

what is the correct way to translate it?

My full failed translation looks like this

```
app.post('/content/uploads', function(req, res){
  upload(function(req, res, (err)){
    if(err){
      res.render('index', {
        msg: err
      });
    } else {
      console.log(req.file);
      res.send('test');
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you wrapper err within brackets like this `upload(function(req, res, (err)){`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you spend some time getting comfortable with the arrow syntax, it's not "abnormal".

In any case, you may find this tool useful: https://babeljs.io/en/repl

You can paste code and select only `ES2015` on the left (uncheck the others) and see how it translates the code.

For example, it will output:

```
app.post('/content/uploads', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send('testing');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! yeah i should, but im really new to this and im not familiar yet with it, and following someone else example using it is kind of confusing, thats why i try to "translate" it

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/content/uploads', function (req,res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send('testing');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
upload(req, res, (err)=>{
    //TODO
});
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
var someFunc = (err)=>{
    //TODO
};
upload(req, res, someFunc);
```

So, you can write it with `function` keyword like this:

```
upload(req, res, function (err) {
    //TODO
});
```